# Will my upgrades be available when I replay missions?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've been saving up all my credits. I'm at level 23 now and I'm going to replay all the missions to get the achievements. Will the upgrades I buy *now* apply to the missions I replay? Will any of them? Some of them? How doe sit work?

Comment: Uhh, even if that did work, why save up?  It's not like you're earning interest, and the upgrades aren't getting any cheaper...

Comment: The only reason to do this is to get all of the upgrade achievements in one go. (Save, buy all of one category, load, buy all of another category, etc.)

Comment: Yes, the easiest way to get all the armory and mercenary achievements are to play through quickly on casual and don't spend any of your credits until you're ready to farm the achievements.

Comment: @BlueRaja: You might save up credits to burn them on the later-game units.  Whether or not that's a good idea...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you replay a mission you only have the upgrades you had the first time you played through

As @Raven pointed out in the comments in the branching missions if you replay the other path you'll have all the current upgrades.  When I finally got around to playing Safe Haven I had battlecruisers already.

Comment: So I shot myself in the foot? Awesome.

Comment: This is not completely correct -- I think that you might be able to use ALL upgrades if your replay the "either or" mission that you skipped when you first had to make the choice. But generally, Davy8 is correct.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that part but you are correct.

Comment: Yeah... I just played one of those, and it was so easy :)